# Is it possible to write generic bucket sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, bucket-sort

As we know, bucket sort algorythm is very efficient: its running time is around O(N + m), where N is the number of items to be sorted, and m is the size of array to use fpr sorting. The problem is that it is suitable only for a limited set of keys: integers, which fill into the size of our array.

**The question: is there some ways to use it for an arbitrary type of the key?**

For example, if we have some arbitrary key, we can use its hashcode as a bucket index. Of course, we need to preserve the rule: if key1 > key2 then hashcode1 > hashcode2 etc

Is it possible to implement this?

For example, if we need to sort the strings, its easy to obtain the bucket indexes of strings built from its character representations.

Comment: If there is a function `f(k) -> a[0..m]` (such that the ordering is maintained). One problem is that bucket sort is less ideal as m >> N.

Comment: Its more practical to require the converse rule: if hashcode(k1) > hashcode(k2) then k1 > k2, though that means you then need a secondary  sort within buckets.

Answer (score 1):

The runtime you're giving - O(n + M) - and the fact that you're saying that the algorithm only works for integers makes me think that you're referring to [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) rather than bucket sort. If you're curious whether it's always possible to find a way to give objects arbitrary indices like hash codes such that they can be counting sorted, then the answer is *no*, it's not always possible to do this.

Take strings, for example. Suppose that we have some mapping from strings to integers such that if str1 < str2, then code(str1) < code(str2). Now, take the strings "" and "b" and determine code("") and code("b"). We know that code("") < code("b"). Now, define

> k = code("b") - code("") - 1

This is the number of integers between code("") and code("b"), exclusive.

Next, think about the strings "a", "aa", "aaa", "aaaa", etc. until we have k + 1 of them. Notice that

> "" < "a" < "aa" < "aaa" < "aaaa" < "aaaaa" < ... < "b".

This means that we should have

> code("") < code("a") < code("aa") < code("aaa") < code("aaaa") < ... < code("b")

Here's the problem: there are only k distinct integer values between code("") and code("b"), but there are k+1 strings that need to fill in those gaps. This will force two strings to collide and have the same numeric code, causing the sort to fail.

The reason this is a problem is that the integers do not have the same [order type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_type) as many other structures, such as strings, pairs of integers, real numbers, etc.